# Obtaining HTML text from an HTML attribute - Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The questions I looked at all had to do with extracting text from things such as `<p> ... </p>` tags.  What I need to know is if I can extract the text using Selenium for an HTML attribute as such:

```
<li id="bullet" someid="1003"> ... </li>
```

Can I get the `1003` from the `someid` attribute using Selenium if I can grab the proper Web element selecting by its unique id or xpath (this I already know how to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [`getAttribute()`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)) (java) method is for:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(by.id("bullet"));
element.getAttribute("someid");
```

Comment: I actually just found it, too.  Sorry - Didn't know there was a built-in method for this :)  Thanks for your answer, though, I appreciate it.